# Most recent record on left join

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql, i have table A which has account information and B table which has demographic information such as date of birth, address, and insurance policy information(primary,secondary).Table B's insurance feilds is updated so i want the most recent data from table B.Table B dont have any date feild. So how do i get the most recent record from B which is to be joined with A later.

```
select  
   A.num,
   A.openingamount,
   A.action,
   A.current_status,
   B.dob,
   B.primary_policy,
   B.secondary_policy 
from A 
left outer join B 
    on (B.uniqueid = A.ponum) 
where A.num ='123'
```

Comment: Does table B have a auto-increment column? if you have no date and no incrementing number then you can#t find the latest row.

Comment: there is no auto increment and beside what does #t mean? please elaborate.

Comment: increment column means that new records get the highest ID automatically. If last record has id 3 then new record will have id 4.

Answer (score 1):

juergen d is correct in eir comment above, stating that you need *some* ordered column in table B to determine what is the most recent.  If `B.uniqueid` is an auto-incrementing column, then you can use that; if it isn't then you'll need to add a new column by which to order B.

Then, you can get the data with a double-join to B, where the second join is used to find `B` rows that are greater than the max `uniqueid` (i.e. to find *nothing*).

```
SELECT
  A.num, A.openingamount, A.action, A.current_status,
  B.dob, B.primary_policy, B.secondary_policy 
FROM A 
  LEFT JOIN B ON (B.a_ponum = A.ponum) 
  LEFT JOIN B2 ON (B2.a_ponum = A.ponum AND B2.uniqueid > B.uniqueid) 
WHERE
  B2.uniqueid IS NULL
  AND A.num ='123'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a date column, you need an increment column:

```
select  
   A.num,
   A.openingamount,
   A.action,
   A.current_status,
   B.dob,
   B.primary_policy,
   B.secondary_policy 
from A 
left outer join B 
    on (B.uniqueid = A.ponum) 
where A.num ='123'
order by B.increment_id desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You also may want to add an auto-updated TIMESTAMP field -

```
ALTER TABLE B
  ADD COLUMN ts
    TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

[Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html).

Then use this field to find the most recent record.